# Problema en jsp y mysql al listar mas de un registro entre tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, ajax, mvc, jsp, servlets

Estimados tengo un problema al visualizar datos en jsp y mysql con tablas relacionadas.
Lo que ocurre es que al momento de mostrar los datos en una tabla html , si hay mas de un registro, la tabla se desarma quedando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este proyecto esta construido en MVC
packages

cliente,
conexion,
controlador,
dao y
negocio

El código es el siguiente.

En la capa web tengo una carpeta llamada Javascript , la cual tengo los archivos js para hacer dinamica la pagina .

1.-Primero tengo un archivo js llamado modalAsignarVuelo.js la cual tiene una función de ajax para enviar los parámetros a la consulta a través de un servlet.

```
function mostrarVuelosClienteAjax()
{

 var fechaDespegue= $("#fechaSalida").val();   

$.ajax({
  url: "buscarVuelosClienteServlet.do",
  data: {
    fechaSalida: fechaDespegue
  },
  success: function( result ) {
    $( "#desplegarVuelosCliente" ).html( result);
    limpiarCampos();
  }
});
}
```

2.- En la capa controlador tengo la clase servlet llamada BuscarVuelosClienteServlet a donde llega la petición de ajax

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            VuelosDao vuelosClienteDao =new VuelosDao();
    Vuelo vueloCliente=new Vuelo();
    TramoVuelo tramoVueloCliente=new TramoVuelo();
    try
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        tramoVueloCliente.setFechaDespegue(request.getParameter("fechaSalida"));

        ResultSet resultadoVuelosCliente=vuelosClienteDao.buscarVuelosCliente(tramoVueloCliente);

        ArrayList<Vuelo>vueloClie=new ArrayList<Vuelo>();
        ArrayList<TramoVuelo>tramoVueloClie=new ArrayList<TramoVuelo>();

        if(request.getParameter("fechaSalida").isEmpty())
        {
            String errorPrefijoEntrada="No se ingresó datos de entrada";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorPrefijoEntrada", errorPrefijoEntrada);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorFoliosDisponibles.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {

            while(resultadoVuelosCliente.next())
            {
                vueloClie.add(new Vuelo(resultadoVuelosCliente.getInt("SEQ_VLOS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("LNAR_COD_LNAR"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getInt("NUMERO_VLOS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("FECH_VLOS")));
                tramoVueloClie.add(new TramoVuelo(resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("ORI_TRMS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("DES_TRMS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("FECH_DESP_TRMS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("FECH_ARRI_TRMS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("EST_TRMS"),resultadoVuelosCliente.getString("MATRICULA_TRMS")));
            }

            request.getSession().setAttribute("vueloClie", vueloClie);
            request.getSession().setAttribute("tramoVueloClie", tramoVueloClie);

            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table class='table-condensed table-responsive table-hover' style='width: 100%' id='tablaVuelosCliente'>");
                 out.println("<thead>");
                     out.println("<tr class='input-sm'>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Codigo</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Iata</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Numero</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Fecha V</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Origen</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Destino</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>F. Salida</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>F. Llegada</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Estado</th>");
                          out.println("<th class='btn-info '>Matricula</th>");
                     out.println("</tr>");
                 out.println("</thead>");

                out.println("<tbody>");


                      try

                      {

                      for(int i=0; i<vueloClie.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.println("<tr class='input-sm'>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+vueloClie.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+vueloClie.get(i).getIataVuelo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+vueloClie.get(i).getNumeroVuelo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+vueloClie.get(i).getFechaVuelo()+"</td>");

                                        }

                      for(int i=0; i<tramoVueloClie.size(); i++)
                                        {

                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getOrigenTramo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getDestinoTramo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getFechaDespegue()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getFechaArribo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getEstadoTramo()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+tramoVueloClie.get(i).getMatriculaTramo()+"</td>");
                                        }


                      }
                      catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                      {
                          out.print("</tr>");
                      }



                 out.println("</tbody>");
                 out.println("</table>");

                 out.println("</body>");
                 out.println("</html>");


        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BuscarVuelosClienteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

3.- en la capa dao tengo la clase VuelosDao la cual tiene un metodo con la consulta sql a la que va el servlet a buscar los datos.

```
public ResultSet buscarVuelosCliente(TramoVuelo t)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        String SQL="";

        SQL="select * from verVuelosCliente where fech_desp_trms='"+t.getFechaDespegue()+"';";
        res=st.executeQuery(SQL);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VuelosDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;
}
```

4.- Las clases del paquete negocio que utilizo son 2 , una llamada Vuelos y la otra TramoVuelo

Clase Vuelo.

```
package negocio;


public class Vuelo {

private int idVuelo;
private String iataVuelo;
private int numeroVuelo;
private String fechaVuelo;
private String estadoVuelo;
private String tipoTransitoVuelo;
private String fechaCreacionVuelo;
private String rutaVuelo;
private String vuelo;

public Vuelo()
{
    idVuelo=0;
    iataVuelo="";
    numeroVuelo=0;
    fechaVuelo="";
    estadoVuelo="";
    tipoTransitoVuelo="";
    fechaCreacionVuelo="";
    rutaVuelo="";
    vuelo="";
}
public Vuelo(int idVuelo, String iataVuelo, int numeroVuelo, String fechaVuelo, String estadoVuelo, String tipoTransitoVuelo, String fechaCreacionVuelo, String rutaVuelo,String vuelo) 
{
    this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
    this.iataVuelo = iataVuelo;
    this.numeroVuelo = numeroVuelo;
    this.fechaVuelo = fechaVuelo;
    this.estadoVuelo = estadoVuelo;
    this.tipoTransitoVuelo = tipoTransitoVuelo;
    this.fechaCreacionVuelo = fechaCreacionVuelo;
    this.rutaVuelo = rutaVuelo;
    this.vuelo=vuelo;
}

public Vuelo(int idVuelo,String iataVuelo,int numeroVuelo,String fechaVuelo)
{
    this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
    this.iataVuelo = iataVuelo;
    this.numeroVuelo = numeroVuelo;
    this.fechaVuelo=fechaVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the idVuelo
 */
public int getIdVuelo() {
    return idVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param idVuelo the idVuelo to set
 */
public void setIdVuelo(int idVuelo) {
    this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the iataVuelo
 */
public String getIataVuelo() {
    return iataVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param iataVuelo the iataVuelo to set
 */
public void setIataVuelo(String iataVuelo) {
    this.iataVuelo = iataVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the numeroVuelo
 */
public int getNumeroVuelo() {
    return numeroVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param numeroVuelo the numeroVuelo to set
 */
public void setNumeroVuelo(int numeroVuelo) {
    this.numeroVuelo = numeroVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the fechaVuelo
 */
public String getFechaVuelo() {
    return fechaVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param fechaVuelo the fechaVuelo to set
 */
public void setFechaVuelo(String fechaVuelo) {
    this.fechaVuelo = fechaVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the estadoVuelo
 */
public String getEstadoVuelo() {
    return estadoVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param estadoVuelo the estadoVuelo to set
 */
public void setEstadoVuelo(String estadoVuelo) {
    this.estadoVuelo = estadoVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the tipoTransitoVuelo
 */
public String getTipoTransitoVuelo() {
    return tipoTransitoVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param tipoTransitoVuelo the tipoTransitoVuelo to set
 */
public void setTipoTransitoVuelo(String tipoTransitoVuelo) {
    this.tipoTransitoVuelo = tipoTransitoVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the fechaCreacionVuelo
 */
public String getFechaCreacionVuelo() {
    return fechaCreacionVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param fechaCreacionVuelo the fechaCreacionVuelo to set
 */
public void setFechaCreacionVuelo(String fechaCreacionVuelo) {
    this.fechaCreacionVuelo = fechaCreacionVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the rutaVuelo
 */
public String getRutaVuelo() {
    return rutaVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param rutaVuelo the rutaVuelo to set
 */
public void setRutaVuelo(String rutaVuelo) {
    this.rutaVuelo = rutaVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the vuelo
 */
public String getVuelo() {
    return vuelo;
}

/**
 * @param vuelo the vuelo to set
 */
public void setVuelo(String vuelo) {
    this.vuelo = vuelo;
}
```

}

Clase TramoVuelo.

```
package negocio;


public class TramoVuelo{

private int idTramo;
private int idVuelo;
private String origenTramo;
private String destinoTramo;
private String fechaDespegue;
private String fechaArribo;
private String matriculaTramo;
private String estadoTramo;

public TramoVuelo() {
    idTramo=0;
    idVuelo=0;
    origenTramo="";
    destinoTramo="";
    fechaDespegue="";
    fechaArribo="";
    matriculaTramo="";
    estadoTramo="";
}




public TramoVuelo(int idTramo, int idVuelo, String origenTramo, String destinoTramo, String fechaDespegue, String fechaArribo, String matriculaTramo, String estadoTramo) {
    this.idTramo = idTramo;
    this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
    this.origenTramo = origenTramo;
    this.destinoTramo = destinoTramo;
    this.fechaDespegue = fechaDespegue;
    this.fechaArribo = fechaArribo;
    this.matriculaTramo = matriculaTramo;
    this.estadoTramo = estadoTramo;
}

public TramoVuelo(String origenTramo,String destinoTramo,String fechaDespegue,String fechaArribo)
{
    this.origenTramo = origenTramo;
    this.destinoTramo = destinoTramo;
    this.fechaDespegue = fechaDespegue;
    this.fechaArribo = fechaArribo;
}

public TramoVuelo(String origenTramo,String destinoTramo,String fechaDespegue,String fechaArribo,String estadoTramo,String matriculaTramo)
{
    this.origenTramo = origenTramo;
    this.destinoTramo = destinoTramo;
    this.fechaDespegue = fechaDespegue;
    this.fechaArribo = fechaArribo;
this.estadoTramo=estadoTramo;
    this.matriculaTramo=matriculaTramo;

}



/**
 * @return the idTramo
 */
public int getIdTramo() {
    return idTramo;
}

/**
 * @param idTramo the idTramo to set
 */
public void setIdTramo(int idTramo) {
    this.idTramo = idTramo;
}

/**
 * @return the idVuelo
 */
public int getIdVuelo() {
    return idVuelo;
}

/**
 * @param idVuelo the idVuelo to set
 */
public void setIdVuelo(int idVuelo) {
    this.idVuelo = idVuelo;
}

/**
 * @return the origenTramo
 */
public String getOrigenTramo() {
    return origenTramo;
}

/**
 * @param origenTramo the origenTramo to set
 */
public void setOrigenTramo(String origenTramo) {
    this.origenTramo = origenTramo;
}

/**
 * @return the destinoTramo
 */
public String getDestinoTramo() {
    return destinoTramo;
}

/**
 * @param destinoTramo the destinoTramo to set
 */
public void setDestinoTramo(String destinoTramo) {
    this.destinoTramo = destinoTramo;
}

/**
 * @return the fechaDespegue
 */
public String getFechaDespegue() {
    return fechaDespegue;
}

/**
 * @param fechaDespegue the fechaDespegue to set
 */
public void setFechaDespegue(String fechaDespegue) {
    this.fechaDespegue = fechaDespegue;
}

/**
 * @return the fechaArribo
 */
public String getFechaArribo() {
    return fechaArribo;
}

/**
 * @param fechaArribo the fechaArribo to set
 */
public void setFechaArribo(String fechaArribo) {
    this.fechaArribo = fechaArribo;
}

/**
 * @return the matriculaTramo
 */
public String getMatriculaTramo() {
    return matriculaTramo;
}

/**
 * @param matriculaTramo the matriculaTramo to set
 */
public void setMatriculaTramo(String matriculaTramo) {
    this.matriculaTramo = matriculaTramo;
}

/**
 * @return the estadoTramo
 */
public String getEstadoTramo() {
    return estadoTramo;
}

/**
 * @param estadoTramo the estadoTramo to set
 */
public void setEstadoTramo(String estadoTramo) {
    this.estadoTramo = estadoTramo;
}
```

}

Si en la consulta retorna 1 solo registro, entonces este se muestra correctamente en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si la consulta retorna mas de un registro, la tabla se desordena.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda ya que la consulta a la base de datos trae los datos correctamente. Debe ser un problema en el objeto de una de las clases o del servlet pero no creo porque con 1 registro trae los datos bien pero con mas de un registros los trae mal.

```
select * from verVuelosCliente where fech_desp_trms='2019-02-07';
```

La tabla "verVuelosCliente" es una vista hecha de 2 tablas "Tabla Vlos(Vuelos) y Trms (Tramos)
la consulta está hecha para mostrar los datos de vuelos y tramos haciendo join en las 2 tablas y el resultado lo almacené en la vista "verVuelosCliente" , la consulta de la vista recibe como parametro un dato de tipo fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Estimados, me podrían ayudar por favor ya que he intentado de muchas formas y sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema, la tabla se desordena y necesito solución este tema para presentar mi proyecto este miércoles. Cualquier ayuda se los agradeceré . gracias

Comment: Estimados , me podrían ayudar con este tema por favor. ya que la consulta sql funciona bien, pero se me desordena la tabla cuando veo la lista de datos.

Comment: Podrá ser la tabla html , la arquitectura o la consulta sql ? la consulta sql al menos desde el motor trae los datos bien , pero en el programa desordena la tabla html. Utilice varios tipo de tablas y ocurre lo mismo

Comment: Me podrían ayudar por favor con este tema.

Comment: Hola buenos días me podrían ayudar por favor con este tema?, la tabla verVuelosCliente es en realizad una vista creada de varias tablas . Será que hay que agrupar las columnas para evitar el problema en la tabla html?